# About a "natural" module

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Take $A$ a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and take $U$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and $Z_1,Z_2$ two $A$-modules. Now, $$U\otimes_\mathbb{K}Z_1\oplus Z_2$$ is a natural $A$-module with the trivial sum and scalar product given by: $$a(u\otimes z_1+z_2)=u\otimes az_1 + az_2.$$
My question is: Is this right?

Comment: An argument would be to verify the module axioms.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.